# USB device on website

Tags: php, web-services, usb

Is it possible  to use a USB device peripheral that I have created directly on a website. 
I am not sure how to start, but for example, on websites like  connect.garmin.com they allow you to connect your Sat Nav and then transfer the data to the website after you have downloaded a application and restarted your browser.

What do I need to research to add this functionality with a particular device I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly? Generally not.

Browsers run websites are run in highly sandboxed environments. If you want to access a USB device you will need:

- Drivers for the OS
- Heightened security privileges
- An interface (which will usually be fairly limited in its environments, e.g. ActiveX for IE/Windows)

If you have an application, then it just needs to load an HTTP library, make use of a webservice that you provide, then open a URL (in the default browser) which is related to the updated data (e.g. by a unique ID returned by the webservice).

Comment: Plugins that utilize devices can be written in some cross platform languages like Java & Flash. A simple applet or the bane of the web's existence that is a Flash program should be able to interact with your device. ActiveX is also a solution but again only on Windows.

Comment: So, I could use Flash as the direct interface to the device? 
Any other directions you can point me before I begin the task.

Comment: Also David, the intention is to allow people with the devices, to access my website and then use the device on the website. Its only basic transfers of information. Very minimal complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a browser plug-in for this. In Garmin's case, it is [Garmin Communicator](http://www.garmin.com/products/communicator/).

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded that and installed to get my USB GPS working when I use their website. 

I would like t oknow what I need to research to create something like this myself.